# R: gsub/replace only those occurrences following a keyword occurrence

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I only want to replace string occurrences that follow a particular keyword/pattern and not before. in other words, do nothing until the first occurrence of the keyword-pattern, and then start to gsub to the right of that keyword-pattern. See below:

```
gsub("\\[|\\]", "", "ab[ cd] ef keyword [ gh ]keyword ij ")
```

Actual results: 
"ab cd ef keyword  gh keyword ij "

Desired results:
 "ab[ cd] [][asfg]  ]] ef keyword  gh keyword ij "

[Edited to fix the results. I don't want to remove 'keyword']
[Edited to show case of multiple occurrences of keyword]

Comment: Is there only 1 occurrence of keyword? See https://regex101.com/r/PUSlfD/1 and in R https://ideone.com/Qhsgxj

Comment: @Thefourthbird not necessarily, and I also had a mistake in the output and just edited to clarify. I don't want to remove "keyword", only to start gsub after the 1st instance of it

Comment: Keyword is not removed in the example, only the following  `[` and `]` What I mean is are there multiple occurrences of keyword in the string? And if so, what is the expected behaviour?

Comment: I edited to show the behavior. And yes, keyword may appear multiple times, and only the 1st occurrence triggers the start of gsub. Subsequent keywords are ignored.

Comment: Do you mean like this? https://regex101.com/r/Z953vX/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use `\G` to get continous matches after keyword. Use `\K` to forget what was matched and match the following `[` or `]` to be replaced with an empty string.

```
(?:^.*?keyword\b|\G(?!^))[^\[\]]*\K[\[\]]
```

In parts

- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `^.*?keyword` Match until the first keyword
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert position at the end of previous match, not at the start to get continuous matches
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `[^\[\]]*\K` Match 0+ times not `[` or `]` and forget what was matched using `\K`
- `[\[\]]` Match either `[` or `]`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zJFKYD/1) | [R demo](https://ideone.com/Qhsgxj)

Your code might look like

```
gsub("(?:^.*?keyword\\b|\\G(?!^))[^\\[\\]]*\\K[\\[\\]]", "", "ab[ cd] ef keyword [ gh ]keyword ij ", perl=T)
```

Note to use `perl=T` at the end for Perl-like regular expressions.